# R Shiny Dashboard valueBox: Animation from one number to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, r, shiny

I am trying to show animation / transition from 0 to a number in valuebox. let's say 92.6 in valuebox. For example, if a value 90.6 needs to be shown, it will be transitioning from 0 to 90.6.

**Example**

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(dplyr)
# UI
ui <- dashboardPage(skin = "black",
                    dashboardHeader(title = "Test"),
                    dashboardSidebar(disable = TRUE),
                    dashboardBody(
                        fluidRow(
                            valueBoxOutput("test_box")
                        )
                    )
)

# Server response
server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$test_box <- renderValueBox({
        iris %>% 
            summarise(Petal.Length = mean(Petal.Length)) %>% 
            .$Petal.Length %>% 
            scales::dollar() %>% 
            valueBox(subtitle = "Unit Sales",
                     icon = icon("server"),
                     color = "purple"
        )
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

In javascript solution is shown here - http://jsfiddle.net/947Bf/1/ In the script below, I tried to communicate using shiny.addCustomMessageHandler but couldn't get success.

```
tags$script("
 Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('testmessage',
 function(){
    var o = {value : 0};
    $.Animation( o, {
        value: $('#IRR .inner h3').val()
      }, { 
        duration: 1500,
        easing : 'easeOutCubic'
      }).progress(function(e) {
          $('#IRR .inner h3').text((e.tweens[0].now).toFixed(1));
    });

  });"),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example. The parameter `easing: 'easeOutCubic'` causes some errors, so I removed this line.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

js <- "
Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('anim',
 function(x){
    
    var $s = $('div.small-box div.inner h3'); 
    var o = {value: 0};
    $.Animation( o, {
        value: x
      }, { 
        duration: 1500
        //easing: 'easeOutCubic'
      }).progress(function(e) {
          $s.text('$' + (e.tweens[0].now).toFixed(1));
    });

  }
);"

# UI
ui <- dashboardPage(skin = "black",
                    dashboardHeader(title = "Test"),
                    dashboardSidebar(disable = TRUE),
                    dashboardBody(
                      tags$head(tags$script(js)),
                      fluidRow(
                        valueBox("", subtitle = "Unit Sales",
                                 icon = icon("server"),
                                 color = "purple"
                        )
                      ),
                      br(),
                      actionButton("btn", "Change value")
                    )
)

# Server response
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  rv <- reactiveVal(10)
  
  observeEvent(input[["btn"]], {
    rv(rpois(1,20))
  })
  
  observeEvent(rv(), {
    session$sendCustomMessage("anim", rv())
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

---

## EDIT

Here is a way to change the icon according to `value < 10` or `value > 10`.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

js <- "
Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('anim',
 function(x){
    
    var $icon = $('div.small-box i.fa');
    if(x <= 10 && $icon.hasClass('fa-arrow-up')){
      $icon.removeClass('fa-arrow-up').addClass('fa-arrow-down');
    }
    if(x > 10 && $icon.hasClass('fa-arrow-down')){
      $icon.removeClass('fa-arrow-down').addClass('fa-arrow-up');
    }
    
    var $s = $('div.small-box div.inner h3'); 
    var o = {value: 0};
    $.Animation( o, {
        value: x
      }, { 
        duration: 1500
        //easing: 'easeOutCubic'
      }).progress(function(e) {
          $s.text('$' + (e.tweens[0].now).toFixed(1));
    });

  }
);"

# UI
ui <- dashboardPage(skin = "black",
                    dashboardHeader(title = "Test"),
                    dashboardSidebar(disable = TRUE),
                    dashboardBody(
                      tags$head(tags$script(HTML(js))),
                      fluidRow(
                        valueBox("", subtitle = "Unit Sales",
                                 icon = icon("arrow-up"),
                                 color = "purple"
                        )
                      ),
                      br(),
                      actionButton("btn", "Change value")
                    )
)

# Server response
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  rv <- reactiveVal(10)
  
  observeEvent(input[["btn"]], {
    rv(rpois(1,10))
  })
  
  observeEvent(rv(), {
    session$sendCustomMessage("anim", rv())
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

## EDIT

Here is a way to do such an animated box with an id set to the box. This allows to do multiple animated boxes with the same JS code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

js <- "
Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('anim',
 function(x){

    var $box = $('#' + x.id + ' div.small-box');
    var value = x.value;

    var $icon = $box.find('i.fa');
    if(value <= 10 && $icon.hasClass('fa-arrow-up')){
      $icon.removeClass('fa-arrow-up').addClass('fa-arrow-down');
    }
    if(value > 10 && $icon.hasClass('fa-arrow-down')){
      $icon.removeClass('fa-arrow-down').addClass('fa-arrow-up');
    }

    var $s = $box.find('div.inner h3');
    var o = {value: 0};
    $.Animation( o, {
        value: value
      }, {
        duration: 1500
      }).progress(function(e) {
          $s.text('$' + (e.tweens[0].now).toFixed(1));
    });

  }
);"

# UI
ui <- dashboardPage(
  skin = "black",
  dashboardHeader(title = "Test"),
  dashboardSidebar(disable = TRUE),
  dashboardBody(
    tags$head(tags$script(HTML(js))),
    fluidRow(
      tagAppendAttributes(
        valueBox("", subtitle = "Unit Sales",
                 icon = icon("server"),
                 color = "purple"
        ),
        id = "mybox"
      )
    ),
    br(),
    actionButton("btn", "Change value")
  )
)

# Server response
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  rv <- reactiveVal(10)

  observeEvent(input[["btn"]], {
    rv(rpois(1,20))
  })

  observeEvent(rv(), {
    session$sendCustomMessage("anim", list(id = "mybox", value = rv()))
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  It does not work if I move valuebox to server using renderValueBox() and adding valueBoxOutput in UI. Reason I am doing this is because I want icon to be changed based on value. For e.g. icon = if(value<10) {icon("arrow-down")} else {icon("arrow-up")}

Comment: @UjjawalBhandari We can do that in Javascript within the `addCustomMessageHandler`. See my edit.

Comment: Thanks a ton for your efforts. Highly appreciated. Last request (if you won't mind) - If I have multiple boxes, it shows same value even if I have two reactiveVal of different numbers. I guess it is because of div.small-box. Can you be generous to make this function more generic so that we can use it for any no. of valueboxes?

Comment: @UjjawalBhandari Wrap the `valueBox` in a `div` with an id: `div(id = "myid", valueBox(......))`. Then replace all selectors `$('div.small-box ...')` with `$('#myid div.small-box ...')`.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Thank you for you answer +1. Is there any way to pass the id of the box as an extra argument to `anim`? Otherwise, I don't see how this can work for more than one box. Creating one script for each box, with the id of the box hardcoded into the script would be very time consuming and inelegant.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Amazing, thank you for the very quick fix!!!

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I tried to set the color with a third parameter, via: `var $box = $('#' + x.id + ' div.small-box bg-' +x.col);`, but it does not work. Any thoughts?